# Open downloaded files in iOS app

Tags: ios, uiwebview, download

How can I open downloaded files (images, pdf, word, excel, etc.) in my iOS app? Is there any way to open them using device's system tools like iBooks or this should be done in UIWebView?
[Example](https://www.google.kz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&sqi=2&ved=0CDgQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkebergen.ru%2Fworkdir%2Ffiles%2FFile%2FDubai%2520City%2Fjob.doc&ei=I4twUvb7N4eH4gSSkID4Aw&usg=AFQjCNE6GdJFsLRYcIi_NgpD61Pm94AYpQ&cad=rja).

Comment: One question per post.

Comment: I've divided my questions ;)

Comment: Look into `QLPreviewController` as one option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString* pdfFile = @""; //path of file here



NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfFile];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `QLPreviewController` class.

The apple documentation link is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

**Apple Says**

`A QLPreviewController object, or Quick Look preview controller, provides a specialized view for previewing an item.`

**EDIT:**

A nice tutorial about it:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html

Comment: I think QLPreviewController works for local files. Am I right? Because in tutorial you gave me it is so. I also find [another one](http://ios.biomsoft.com/2012/02/17/load-a-pdf-file-in-the-iphone-app-smoothly/) which doesn't work for me. I have an error: `Couldn't issue file extension for path: /library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/QLPreviewController_Class.pdf`

Comment: I have an URL like in [Example](https://www.google.kz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&sqi=2&ved=0CDgQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkebergen.ru%2Fworkdir%2Ffiles%2FFile%2FDubai%2520City%2Fjob.doc&ei=I4twUvb7N4eH4gSSkID4Aw&usg=AFQjCNE6GdJFsLRYcIi_NgpD61Pm94AYpQ&cad=rja) and need to show content of this file somehow in my app

Comment: There are two ways 1) you can directly show the document or 2) you can download the document to local folder & show it. And both options will download the same amount of data. So the seconds option is better in my opinion. @Yerkezhan.